# JSON - how to find list of child elements based on count

Tags: linq, json.net, linqpad

So I have some JSON data that I want to find the items that appear more than once within a given product node.  See sample data below.
For example, "item": "UT9908" is likely to appear more than once within a given "line" array.  I need to select a list of these items and the count of how many there are within a given product.line array.  Im using Linqpad and the code Im starting with, at least gets me to the point of getting a list of products.  What I really need is a list of items that appear more than once WITHIN a given product.line array.  How can I get that list?

What I get in the code below is an overall list of items and their count.  How can I count WITHIN the line array?

```
var jsonPath = @"d:\temp\1Warehouse_temp_DATA.jsonbak";
        JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(jsonPath));

var deliveries = (from a in o1["order"].Children()["delivery"] select a).ToList();

var product_lines = (from a in deliveries.Children()["product"].Children()["line"] select a).ToList();
//product_lines.Dump();



var items_list = (from a in product_lines.Children()["model_accessory"] 
                    group a by a["item"] into g1 where g1.Count () > 0 
                    select new {item_name = g1.Key, cnt = g1.Count ()} )
                .ToList();                  
items_list.Dump();      





{
  "order": [
    {
      "location": "TTY",
      "osn": "1888TYHHIO",
      "order_type": null,
      "osn_status": "Delivered",
      "order_date": "03012017",
      "customer_name": "234234 test dr",
      "customer_tol_account": null,
      "customer_phone": "234234234",
      "freight_terms": "PREPAID & CHARGE",
      "shipping_instructions": "PH 8747474747",
      "shipping_method": "",
      "additional_service": "",
      "tpoints": "1.9",
      "delivery": [
        {
          "delivery_ad": "",
          "osn_type": "TTU",
          "customer_po_number": "234234",
          "rap": "ONOWR",
          "zip_group": "TYTYY",
          "delivery_date": "04132017",
          "delivery_name": "234 ghhhtol",
          "delivery_address_1": "234 tol fr",
          "delivery_address_2": "031807",
          "delivery_city": "Somewhere",
          "delivery_state": "Idaho",
          "delivery_zip": "111223",
          "delivery_phone": [
            {
              "phone_number": "345345345"
            },
            {
              "phone_number": ""
            }
          ],
          "last_updated_date": "",
          "product": [
            {
              "vendor": "UURL",
              "shipment_number": "",
              "ship_date": "",
              "customer_tracking_number": "",
              "line": [
                {
                  "line_number": "",
                  "line_status": "",
                  "model_accessory": {
                    "crated_indicator": "",
                    "item_type": "M",
                    "item": "TTP99874",
                    "product_type": "",
                    "anti_tip_indicator": "",
                    "product_weight": "",
                    "nmfc": "",
                    "carton_code": "",
                    "quantity": "1"                   
                  }
                },
                {
                  "line_number": "",
                  "line_status": "",
                  "model_accessory": {
                    "crated_indicator": "",
                    "item_type": "A",
                    "item": "UT9908",
                    "product_type": "",
                    "anti_tip_indicator": "",
                    "product_weight": "",
                    "nmfc": "",
                    "carton_code": "",
                    "quantity": "1"                    
                  }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You JSON as shown isn't valid.  See https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand right, but anyway:
to do this, you have to deserialize your JSON to .NET object and then apply some LINQ queries to get required info.

Just something like the following:

1. Create the objects (I just missed all fields except needed):

   ```
   public class OrderClass
   {
       /* all other properties... */
       public string location { get; set; }
       public DeliveryClass[] delivery { get; set; }

   }

   public class DeliveryClass
   {
        /* all other properties... */
       public ProductClass[] product { get; set; }
   }

   public class ProductClass
   {
        /* all other properties... */
       public LineClass[] line { get; set; }

       /* add a method which returns a count of specific lines*/
       public int LineSpecificCount(string s)
       {
           return this.line.Count(l => l.model_accessory.item.Equals(s));
       }
   }

   public class LineClass
   {
        /* all other properties... */
       public model_accessoryClass model_accessory { get; set; }
   }

   public class model_accessoryClass
   {
        /* all other properties... */
       public string item { get; set; }
       public string item_type { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Then:

```
    // get your all orders
    OrderClass[] myOrders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderClass[]>(o1["order"].ToString());

    // get orders where item == "UT9908"
    OrderClass[] ordersWithSpecificLine = myOrders.Where(o => o.delivery.Any(d => d.product.Any(p => p.line.Any(l => l.model_accessory.item.Equals("UT9908"))))).ToArray();

    // get all lines in all orders where item == "UT9908"
    LineClass[] lines = myOrders.SelectMany(o => o.delivery.SelectMany(d => d.product.SelectMany(p => p.line.Where(l => l.model_accessory.item.Equals("UT9908"))))).ToArray();
```

**EDITED:**

```
   // get all products
   ProductClass[] myproducts = orders1.SelectMany(o => o.delivery.SelectMany(d => d.product)).ToArray();

   // and now you can access a count something like
   ProductClass[] productsWithSpecificLine = myproducts.Where(p => p.LineSpecificCount("UT9908") > 0).ToArray();

   // productsWithSpecificLine[0].LineSpecificCount("UT9908") == 2
   // productsWithSpecificLine[1].LineSpecificCount("UT9908") == 1
```

P.S. I have edited your JSON due to some errors inside its structure, and also have added additional line items:

```
{
"order": [{
    "location": "TTY",
    "osn": "1888TYHHIO",
    "order_type": null,
    "osn_status": "Delivered",
    "order_date": "03012017",
    "customer_name": "234234 test dr",
    "customer_tol_account": null,
    "customer_phone": "234234234",
    "freight_terms": "PREPAID & CHARGE",
    "shipping_instructions": "PH 8747474747",
    "shipping_method": "",
    "additional_service": "",
    "tpoints": "1.9",
    "delivery": [{
        "delivery_ad": "",
        "osn_type": "TTU",
        "customer_po_number": "234234",
        "rap": "ONOWR",
        "zip_group": "TYTYY",
        "delivery_date": "04132017",
        "delivery_name": "234 ghhhtol",
        "delivery_address_1": "234 tol fr",
        "delivery_address_2": "031807",
        "delivery_city": "Somewhere",
        "delivery_state": "Idaho",
        "delivery_zip": "111223",
        "delivery_phone": [{
            "phone_number": "345345345"
        },
        {
            "phone_number": ""
        }],
        "last_updated_date": "",
        "product": [{
            "vendor": "UURL",
            "shipment_number": "",
            "ship_date": "",
            "customer_tracking_number": "",
            "line": [{
                "line_number": "",
                "line_status": "",
                "model_accessory": {
                    "crated_indicator": "",
                    "item_type": "M",
                    "item": "TTP99874",
                    "product_type": "",
                    "anti_tip_indicator": "",
                    "product_weight": "",
                    "nmfc": "",
                    "carton_code": "",
                    "quantity": "1"
                }
            },
            {
                "line_number": "",
                "line_status": "",
                "model_accessory": {
                    "crated_indicator": "",
                    "item_type": "A",
                    "item": "UT9908",
                    "product_type": "",
                    "anti_tip_indicator": "",
                    "product_weight": "",
                    "nmfc": "",
                    "carton_code": "",
                    "quantity": "1"
                }
            },
            {
                "line_number": "",
                "line_status": "",
                "model_accessory": {
                    "crated_indicator": "",
                    "item_type": "B",
                    "item": "UT9908",
                    "product_type": "",
                    "anti_tip_indicator": "",
                    "product_weight": "",
                    "nmfc": "",
                    "carton_code": "",
                    "quantity": "1"
                }
            }]
        },
        {
            "vendor": "UURL",
            "shipment_number": "",
            "ship_date": "",
            "customer_tracking_number": "",
            "line": [{
                "line_number": "",
                "line_status": "",
                "model_accessory": {
                    "crated_indicator": "",
                    "item_type": "Z",
                    "item": "TTP99874",
                    "product_type": "",
                    "anti_tip_indicator": "",
                    "product_weight": "",
                    "nmfc": "",
                    "carton_code": "",
                    "quantity": "1"
                }
            },
            {
                "line_number": "",
                "line_status": "",
                "model_accessory": {
                    "crated_indicator": "",
                    "item_type": "X",
                    "item": "UT9908",
                    "product_type": "",
                    "anti_tip_indicator": "",
                    "product_weight": "",
                    "nmfc": "",
                    "carton_code": "",
                    "quantity": "1"
                }
            },
            {
                "line_number": "",
                "line_status": "",
                "model_accessory": {
                    "crated_indicator": "",
                    "item_type": "Y",
                    "item": "UT9909",
                    "product_type": "",
                    "anti_tip_indicator": "",
                    "product_weight": "",
                    "nmfc": "",
                    "carton_code": "",
                    "quantity": "1"
                }
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
}
```

Comment: I'm doing that in the application Im working on and just using LINQpad as a way to test.  However, without concrete types to work with, the LINQ projections / statements are getting a little "obtuse".  So, with your suggestion I think I will bring in the classes I need into the LINQpad query.

Comment: I have added a new method LineSpecificCount into the ProductClass. So it can be used to get a count of lines with appropriate item value.